# Repeating user input Python

Tags: python, pandas, input

I am trying to ask a user how many family members they know information about, between 1-9 based on my algorithm. I want to have the number they chose to run the questions that number of times, so if they know 3 family members it would repeat the questions 3 times. After asking the questions I want to store the responses in variables specific to each person, the previous example would create 3 different storage variables. This is what I have:

```py
import pandas as pd

while True:
    try:
        familynumber = int(input("How many family member info do you have? Please select from 1 - 9 "))
for i in familynumber:
    age = int(input("Please enter your Age: "))
    ldlc = int(input("Please enter you LDL-C Level: "))
    totalc = int(input("Please enter your Total-C Level: "))
    clinicalCAD = int(input("Does someone have clinical CAD: "))
    gender = input("Please enter a gender ").lower()
    onsetAge = int(input("Please enter CAD onset age: "))
    tx = int(input("Does someone have Tandon Xanthoma: "))

p1input = pd.DataFrame([age, ldlc, totalc, clinicalCAD, gender, onsetAge, tx])
```

I just cannot wrap my head around how to attack this task. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `for i in range(familynumber):`

Comment: I would also create the dataframe first, then insert the values either as you get them or in bulk at the end, but *before* going through the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code

```
import pandas as pd

familynumber = int(input("How many family member info do you have? Please select from 1 - 9 "))

# Define the dataframe
p1input = pd.DataFrame(columns=["age", "ldlc", "totalc", "clinicalCAD", "gender", "onsetAge", "tx"])

# Use range to go in a loop
for i in range(familynumber):
    age = int(input("Please enter your Age: "))
    ldlc = int(input("Please enter you LDL-C Level: "))
    totalc = int(input("Please enter your Total-C Level: "))
    clinicalCAD = int(input("Does someone have clinical CAD: "))
    gender = input("Please enter a gender ").lower()
    onsetAge = int(input("Please enter CAD onset age: "))
    tx = int(input("Does someone have Tandon Xanthoma: "))

    # Add row by row to the dataframe
    p1input.loc[i] = [age, ldlc, totalc, clinicalCAD, gender, onsetAge, tx]

# print head to verify
print(p1input.head())
```

Comment: The `tx` line is going to fail - you can't call `int()` on a Y/N answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a namedtuple to create a simple object that will represent family members.  You can then store each person object in your loop to a list of persons.

**example**

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Define a Person namedtuple object to store data
Person = namedtuple("Person", "age ldlc totalc clinicalCAD gender onsetAge tx")

# Iterate over family members and generate Person objects
persons = []
familynumber = int(input("How many family member info do you have? Please select from 1 - 9: "))
for i in range(familynumber):
    print(f"{'-'*20}\nQuestions for person #{i+1}:\n{'-'*20}")
    p = Person(
        age = int(input("Please enter your Age: ")),
        ldlc = int(input("Please enter you LDL-C Level: ")),
        totalc = int(input("Please enter your Total-C Level: ")),
        clinicalCAD = input("Does someone have clinical CAD: "),
        gender = input("Please enter a gender ").lower(),
        onsetAge = int(input("Please enter CAD onset age: ")),
        tx = input("Does someone have Tandon Xanthoma: ")
    )

    # Store person in persons list
    persons.append(p)

# Each person stored in the "persons" list can now be accessed
print(f"{persons = }")
print(f"{persons[0].age = }")
```

Comment: I also fixed the tx input as you were casting it to a integer even though it's technically a string yes/no question.